# Data capture in psychological treatments - nonmandatory random repeat questions

Tags: experiment-design, survey, psychology, qualitative

this is a query for approaching a prospective exploratory study in psychological treatments

*It is not very easy to monitor response to psychological interventions*. Usually there are standardized questionnaires applied monthly, or even weekly. They suffer from learning effects and the fact they may become boring, even irritating / intrusive as people always *have* to go through the same questions in the same order.

To avoid this I thought of a **setting** as follows:

- People are repeatedly attending psychology sessions over a year once a week
- They are provided ample opportunities to answer random questions from 3 or 4 groups
  (e.g. emotional change, therapeutic factors, attitude towards this data collection process, personality)
- There are standard also outcome measures as well at the beginning and end of treatment, and a control group with the standardized questionnaire process only.

Key aspect - capturing answers should be very easy. E.g. - a few terminals in the waiting room. In addition the same survey interface is accessible also from web / mobile devices - if patients wish to enter data also outside treatment provision place.

The idea is to encourage people to answer as many questions as they like, the suggested minimum being 3 questions after each session. In addition there always is also an opportunity to write in free text as well.

At present I think there could be about 60 patients in the study and the same number in the control group.

**Purpose:**

- explore opportunities for data capture during therapy
- compare this methodology to standard questionnaire methodology
- explore factors correlating with outcomes in treatment
- explore peoples' attitudes towards data collection in such manner (including the possibility that it may be another way of engaging patients better with the therapeutic process - as they may choose to provide data during the week between sessions as well)

Evn though I have some practice with data analysis in R, I am not experienced in questions of methodology and study design.

The areas that I need help most at present would be:

**1)** Could you suggest any **sources of information** on qualitative research relevant to the above?

**2)** What would you suggest as the maximum **number of questions** in each question group that still might produce useful data? (More questions provide more variety, but less chance that all repondents would answer the same questions eventually, and this itself may correlate with outcome)

Any help, comments criticisms would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, probably it is a bad question. Nevertheless an important one for me.

Comment: Have you tought about consulting other psychologist about your design ? My lack of knowledge in psychology research prevent an answer about question 2 (it is not a statistical question).

Comment: Thanks Emilie, I did check with some colleagues, indeed with some before this post, and they all say it is an interesting idea and could be a good way how to gather new data, but they query as to how this could be worked on statistically and I am just learning data analysis, with gusto, but still short of a good answer)).

Comment: Then I think you should contact a statistician...if nobody did it before, you must be sure it will be possible to analyze your design.